# F.lux does not always work on resolution changes. Is there a way to check if the resolution changes?

Tags: applescript, display, color

I'm a happy user of [f.lux](http://stereopsis.com/flux/), but sometimes when I plug in my external monitor on my macbook air it returns to full brightness. This also sometimes happens if I unplug my external monitor and switch to the laptop screen only.

I see f.lux switching on and off for a brief moment.

What I wanted to do about this is to somehow detect a screen resolution change, so I could use this to write an applescript to restart f.lux whenever this occurs.

All I could find until now is this discussion about detecting resolution changes:
http://support.realsoftware.com/listarchives/realbasic-nug/2006-02/msg03063.html

But hopefully someone has any pointers how to achieve this in an easier way or has a different solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try downloading again or ensure that the about box says "v18.0"? v18 should fix this bug (we haven't pushed the auto-update due to some unresolved issues with hybrid graphics cards.)

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded the latest version I do see "Version 18" now (previous is said nothing). I will try it out and mark this as the answer when it works. :)